# Подключение к базе данных без клиента

Tags: c#, oracle

Подскажите пожалуйста в следующем вопросе - нужно ли устанавливать Oracle Client на мою Windows машину для работы с БД и разработки клиентского приложения,  если база установлена на мой клиент на виртуальной машине?

Comment: давно не работал с базами данных, но, насколько я помню, для подключения к БД вам достаточно иметь драйвер для подключения и все. При этом не важно где и как запущен сервер, главное, чтобы он был доступен для подключения.